# how to set label for listings? (lyx)

Tags: listings, captions, lyx, labels

i would set a label at listings like on figures.
If I use the label command there is no label for reference

Comment: Hi, welcome. How do you insert the listing?

Comment: with insert->programm listing

Comment: OK. Captions/labels is actually a bit easier I think if you use Insert -> File -> Child Document, and use "Program listing" as include type. But give me some minutes and I'll explain one way of doing this with Insert -> Program listing as well.

Comment: while using child document label could set but the references doesn't show the numbers like in figures

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Note that you *must* have a caption to get a number.

Comment: yes the caption is set. If I use namereference it works well. But if i would like a reference on the number of listing it displays question marks.
Maybe cause the label has no prefix.

Comment: The standard cross reference type (`<Reference`) should work fine, and prefixes are irrelevant in that case.

Comment: Ok the problem is the special character ü. Without it works. Thx
But in figures they worked as well.

Comment: Did you have that in the label (which I don't think you should), or the caption?

Comment: in both before. But without that in label it works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts here, one for the Insert -> Program listing, one for using child documents, at the end.

## Insert -> Program listing

After making your listing with Insert -> Program listing, right click in the inset and open the Settings:

[image: opening settings of inset]

Settings:

[image: settings dialog]

In the "Main settings" tab you can change various parameters, such as setting the language in the bottom left. But to add caption and label, go to the Advanced tab:

[image: Advanced settings]

Configuration of `listings` is done via `key=value` pairs, and you can write such in the empty white rectangle on the right part of this dialog. Perhaps unsurprisingly, there are `caption` and `label` keys, so you can write something like `caption={bla bla, bla}, label=foo`. This will then look like this, after you hit the *Apply* button:

[image: added caption and label]

Note that you **must** include a caption. It is the caption that is numbered, so without it you wont get a number, the label alone isn't enough.

Press OK or Close to close the dialog. You're not quite done yet though. LyX doesn't see this label in its cross-reference system, so if you try Insert --> Cross reference, you fill not find `foo` there.

To trick LyX into being able to use that label, place the cursor right before or after the listing (doesn't actually matter where), and do Insert --> Note --> LyX Note. Inside this note, insert a label that you call `foo` (use exactly the same name as you did for the listing):

[image: LyX note with label]

Now, if you do Insert --> Cross reference, the `foo` label appears in the list:

[image: insert cross reference dialog]

## Child document

Another way of making a listing is to include a file with code directly, using Insert -> File -> Child document, and setting the "Include type" to "Program listing". Here you can set the caption and label directly, and no tricks are need to get LyX to see the label:

[image: insert child document]